# SQL Server Date time issue while inserting a record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, DateOfBirth)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', '30/09/2014');
```

**Note**: `DateOFBirth` is in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

But in SQL Server database table, it is inserting in the `yyyy/dd/mm` format but not in `yyyy/mm/dd` format.

Please help me resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server doesn't store a `DateTime` in any string format - it's stored as an 8 byte numerical value.

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is shown to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

So in your **concrete case**, you should use:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, 
                       City, PostalCode, DateOfBirth)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 
        'Stavanger', '4006', '20140930');
```

to properly insert "Sept 30, 2014" into your table - how it's shown is dependent on what settings your SSMS or other front-end tool has.